# Use SQL to select fields from wordpress listings

Tags: sql, wordpress, select, field

I'm using a WordPress theme which can store a lot of information, which I'm quite keen on accessing.

I'm trying to access the latitude and longitude (which are stored as a field called 'location'). These are stored in WordPress posts, with a post type 'listing'.

I can get this to work, but it doesn't give me the fields I need:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT ID, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type='listing' ";
$value = $wpdb->get_results($query);
print_r($value);
```

When I add in the location field (like below), it doesn't work. The array is returned blank.

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT ID, post_title, location FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type='listing' ";
$value = $wpdb->get_results($query);
print_r($value);
```

I've also tried putting location inside quotation marks, but then I get a result like this, for each listing:

> Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 5299 [post_title] => My post
>   title [location] => location )

I need to be able to access the latitude and longitude which are stored inside the location field. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: There is no such column as location in wp_posts , you should have stored it in wp_postmeta as meta data

Comment: I think it might be stored there Adeel. How do I access it?

Comment: I've solved this myself... The SQL is now: $query = "SELECT p.ID, pm.meta_key, pm.meta_value
FROM $wpdb->posts p
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta pm
 ON pm.post_id = p.ID
 AND pm.meta_key = 'location'
WHERE p.post_type= 'listing' 
 AND p.post_status='publish'
GROUP BY p.ID";

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your meta key is 'location' , so you can retreive it by this way. You have to pass the post id as the first parameter.

```
   $location = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'location' );
```

For more info.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

OR

If you want it your way then :

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT  meta_id, meta_value  FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key ='location' ";
$value = $wpdb->get_results($query);
print_r($value);
```